# What HTTPResponse code should be returned from Azure Mobile Services custom login?

Tags: ios, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I am on an Azure Mobile Services custom API project with custom authentication implemented as described here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/,
And one of the iOS client developers has raised an issue that consumption of this custom login (not using client libs) is failing, and apparently because this **401 response** does not conform to HTTP auth protocol (**no authentication challenge header**). The proposal here is that 401 should not be used in this scenario, but 403 instead. 
Can someone elaborate on the problem here and what the best general approach is?
Should the 401 returned be augmented with some additional headers? Why would iOS have trouble with this? I have not confirmed that AMS is not sending the header.

Comment: are you added all files which are using in Azure????

Comment: And make sure your Azure credentials are correct(AzureServiceAccount,AzureServiceAccountaccessKey,BlobUploadUrl,WebApiUrl).

Comment: @Mihir. This is unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 403 means forbidden, as in we know who you are, but you do not have permission to get or act on this resource. I don't think it's the correct response in your case here.

HTTP 401 is the correct response, but it should have a [`WWW-Authenticate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.16) header in the response to identify the scheme and realm to which the user should authenticate.

You'll need to add this header to your response manually.

```
response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
    "realm=\"" + AuthRealm + "\""));
```

Comment: Thank you so far, but I need further clarification. Why do all clients work ok but not the ios one, why do Microsoft not add this header in their own examples, and why does the rest API need to offer this header when the login method is called? I am missing something.

Comment: Usually there's only one realm to authenticate against, so most clients know what to do when they receive a 401. Maybe the iOS client is more strict than other clients. Microsoft not adding it in their own examples is probably an oversight on their part.

Comment: Many thanks so far. I will try and understand this a bit further and flag this is as correct later.